# c# library (dll) to decode aac files to wav

Tags: wav, decode, aac

I've found several command line utilities to decode aac to wav (decompress) but I can't seem to find a c# solution to do this.

there is a supposed one here: http://www.rarewares.org/aac-decoders.php

but I couldn't successfully add a reference to that dll in my project, so I'm guessing it's bunk.

anyone know of a c# library that can do this? I'd rather not have to call the command line if I can help it.

TIA

Comment: Which library did you try that didn't work? What was the error?

Comment: libFAAD2 dll for Win32 - error was: "could not be added. make sure the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: That is a Win32 DLL, not based on COM or .NET. However, since it has a set of simple C-callable exported functions, you could use P/Invoke to call the native methods in your .NET code.

Comment: Any updates on this? I can't seem to find anything really helpful in this matter.

Comment: Because I couldn't find any suitable solution, I've ported Jaad: https://github.com/jimm98y/SharpJaad. It's available as a nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpJaad.AAC

Answer (score 0):

I am using faad in my projects, and have created a wrapper for it.  Here it is: http://pastebin.com/zPmaSSPt

Let me know if you need some more information on it.